# new to ajax, Object not found,

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xampp

Hey guys I'm trying to work with AJAX for my first time using Javascript, PHP, and HTML. I have created the following code, and saved it in the htdocs folder in xampp. xampp is up and running but every time I navigate to localhost/foodstore.html nothing works I just get the error "Object not found!" I've Checked my code over a few times with a tutorial Im following, and found and corrected quite a few errors. I was wondering if the Object not found is because of my code or something else I am doing wrong. This is also my first time really using PHP and xampp.  Also is there any other method that you would recommend to learn AJAX?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src="foodStore.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="process()">
        <h3>Quaff Bucket</h3>
            Enter the food you are looking for:
            <input type="text" id="userInput"/>
            <div id="underInput"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('bacon','beans','chicken');
    if(in_array($food,$foodArray)){
        echo 'we do have'.$food.'!';
    }
    elseif($food==''){

    echo 'Please Enter a food you idiot!';
    }
    else{
        echo 'we do not have'.$food.'punk!';
        }
echo'</response>';

?>
```

JS

```
var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("Cant create the object");
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process(){
    //states 4 and 0 mean that the object is free for communication
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        //get the info from the web page
        food = encodeURICompnent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        //   (Request type,where it is sending,should it be handled asynchronously)
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
    else{
        //wait 1 second before trying again
        setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
}
function handleServerResponse(){
    //4= done communicating
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        //200= Object is ok
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            //response is the only child in the xml page data= the response that would be genterated from the PHP
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            //makes underInput= to message
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML='<span style ="color:blue">'+message +'</span>';
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }else{
            alert('something went wrong');
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: did you intend on not putting your files in a folder?

Comment: I did try putting them in a folder named example at one point, within the htdocs folder.